# How meta data looks like after the custom setting definition added to profile?

Tags: profile, customsetting

We enabled this to dev org. I am trying to add 'XXXX' custom setting to admin profile. I am trying to pull profile metadata using workbech. I am unable to see any new changes regarding this salesforce update. Could anyone help on this.?

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_custom_setting_perms.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the extra information, you need to retrieve additional metadata. For example, this package would include a custom setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>CustomSetting__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>Admin</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
  </types>
  <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

In the Profile xml file, you'll see entries like:

```
<customSettingsAccesses>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <name>CustomSetting__c</name>
</customSettingsAccess>
```

Comment: Thank u @sfdcfox